# I want to check collection in mongo db where pixel="446" print the _id in the console and also create a file local to save the data- In JAVA

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is sample collection:

```json
{
   "_id":"2AB4A2C3-1A67-4855-88D6-E29A63E89C7F",
   "updateTS":"ISODate(""2021-08-24T18:27:30.105Z"")",
   "cimp":[
      68023,
      64532,
      84171,
      87547,
      92906,
      94954,
      95059,
      95217,
      99362,
      114811
   ],
   "pixel":[
      "76",
      "446"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use find to get the object first.

```
db.collection.find({"pixel":"446"})
```